# Expected spy on log to equal 'Authentificated failed'

Tags: angular, typescript, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I need to test compare to value. I have tried this exapmle:

I have this component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title= 'Angular'
  constructor() { }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

And in component.spec.ts

```
it(`should have as title 'Angular'`, async(() => {
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    expect(app.title).toEqual('Angular');
}));

it(`should have as title 'Angular'`, async(() => {
  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
  const app = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
  expect(app.title).toEqual('Angular1');
}));
```

I have followed this example that is simple. But now I need to compare my response value with some value

Step1. Html Component

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="login_card_container">
    <div id="login_card" class="card col s12">
      <form [formGroup]="loginForm" (ngSubmit)="onLogin()" class="col s12">
        <h1 id="form_title">Login</h1>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input formControlName="username" id="username" type="text" class="validate" [ngClass]="{invalid: invalidCredentials}">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <input formControlName="password" id="password" type="password" class="validate" [ngClass]="{invalid: invalidCredentials}">
            <label for="password" data-error="Your username/password combination is invalid">Password</label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="login_button_container" class="row">
          <button id="login_button" type="submit" class="btn waves-effect waves-light" [disabled]="!loginForm.valid">
            <i class="fa fa-sign-in left"></i>
            Login
          </button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Step 2: TS Component

```
  onLogin() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.ws.login(
      this.loginForm.controls['username'].value,
      this.loginForm.controls['password'].value)
      .subscribe(
      result => {
        if (result === true) {
        } else {
          this.loading = false;
          this.invalidCredentials = true;
        }
      });
  }
```

This is my first attempt, and show this error

> Expected spy on log to equal 'Authentificated failed'.

In fact this is successful because response from service is this message `Authentificated failed`

```
  it('should notify in console on form submit', () => {
    spyOn(console, 'log');
    component.loginForm.controls['username'].setValue('admin');
    component.loginForm.controls['password'].setValue('11');
    fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('form')).triggerEventHandler('ngSubmit', null);
   fixture.detectChanges()
    expect(console.log).toEqual('Authentificated failed');
  });
```

In this code, I want `toEqual` service response with `('Authentificated failed')` like in first example

Can you suggest my how to compare `result` form service, with some text?

Comment: Spies are asserted with `toHaveBeenCalledWith`, not `toEqual`. console.log is a function, not a string. You don't call console.log anywhere in the code you've provided.

Comment: Yes, but how to implement in code your idea please?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. You're asserting console.log call but there's no console.log.

Comment: Response from web serve when execute     `fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('form')).triggerEventHandler('ngSubmit', null);`
 is `Authentificated failed`, I want to compare response with `('Authentificated failed')` How? How to manage this response?

Comment: There is nothing in the question that could suggest that you're asserting web server response. This makes sense to you because you obviously have seen your own code but not to everyone else. The question should contain https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Any way, you have a problem with testing strategy. You should test how `this.ws.login` works in a different test by testing it directly, and in this test you should mock `this.ws.login` with predefined response. That's how unit testing works.